# Roots of polynomial/exponential function

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, roots

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sigma \in (0,1]$ be fixed.
I am interested in finding the roots of the function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \big(x^2-n^2-\sigma n^2 x\big)e^{x} - \big(x^2-n^2+\sigma n^2 x\big)e^{-3x};
\end{equation}
on $[0,n^2]$, namely solving $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,n^2]$.

I would be happy with an approximation formula, which clearly indicates the dependence on $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Clearly one root is $x=0$.
A way to proceed for finding the other root(s?) could of course be to factor the polynomials appearing in $f$; namely,
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \big(x-\big(n^2\sigma-n\sqrt{n^2\sigma^2+4}\big)\big)\big(x-\big(n^2\sigma+n\sqrt{n^2\sigma^2+4}\big)\big)e^x - \big(x-\big(-n^2\sigma-n\sqrt{n^2\sigma^2+4}\big)\big)\big(x-\big(-n^2\sigma+n\sqrt{n^2\sigma^2+4}\big)\big)e^{-3x}.
\end{equation}
Though, I don't see clearly how one may proceed from here.

Comment: @RyanK do you mind giving more detail on what you mean by this?

Comment: @RyanK This is not the same $f(x)$ as I defined in the question.

Comment: Oops, missed a sign; sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Find approximate solution of the equation
$$\left(x^2-n^2-\sigma n^2 x\right)e^{x} - \left(x^2-n^2+\sigma n^2 x\right)e^{-3x}=0\tag{1}$$
divide by $e^x$.
$$\left(x^2-n^2-\sigma n^2 x\right) - \left(x^2-n^2+\sigma n^2 x\right)e^{-4x}=0$$
$e^{-4x}$ is almost zero (for $x=4$ we have $e^{-4x}\approx 10^{-7}$)

The equation becomes
$$x^2-\sigma n^2x-n^2=0$$
the positive root is
$$x= \frac{n^2 \sigma +n \sqrt{n^2 \sigma ^2+4}}{2}\tag{2}$$

---

Examples

$n= 2,\sigma = \frac{1}{2}$

$(1)$ gives $x\approx 3.236074894631493$

$(2)$ gives $x\approx 3.23606797749979$

$n= 6,\sigma = \frac{5}{12}$

$(1)$ gives $x\approx 17.10468635614927$

$(2)$ gives $x\approx 17.10468635614927$

Answer (score 1):

There is a formal analytical solution to the equation.

Rewrite it as
$$e^{-4x}=\frac {x^2-\sigma n^2 x-n^2 } {x^2+\sigma n^2 x-n^2 }=\frac{(x-a)(x-b) }{(x-c)(x-d)}$$ and the solution is given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the paper).