# Asymptotic formula for roots of a polynomial-like function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, polynomials

Let $\sigma \in (0, 1)$ and $n \geq1$ be given.

How can one rigorously show that the positive root $x_0 \in (0, n)$ of

\begin{equation}
f(x) = (n^2-x^2-\sigma n^2 x)-(n^2-x^2+\sigma n^2x)e^{-4x}
\end{equation}
is of the form
\begin{equation}
x_0 = x^*-\varepsilon_n
\end{equation}
for some $\varepsilon_n$ such that $\varepsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\to+\infty$, and
where $$x^* := \frac12(n\sqrt{n^2\sigma^2+4}-n^2\sigma)$$ is the positive root of $f_1(x) = (n^2-x^2-\sigma n^2x)$?

This question is related and complementary to  [Roots of polynomial/exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946075/roots-of-polynomial-exponential-function).

Comment: I think that it is not true, i.e. $x^\ast - x_0$ does not converges to zero.

Comment: By the way, comparing with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946075/roots-of-polynomial-exponential-function, your function is different. Please check: $(n^2-x^2-\sigma n^2 x)-(n^2-x^2+\sigma n^2x)e^{-4x}$, or $(x^2-n^2-\sigma n^2 x)-(x^2-n^2+\sigma n^2x)e^{-4x}$.

Comment: @RiverLi How do you see that $x^*-x_0$ does not converge to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$g(x) = (n^2-x^2-\sigma n^2 x)-(n^2-x^2+\sigma n^2x)e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}}.$$
Since $0 < x_0 < x^\ast = \frac{4n^2}{2(n\sqrt{n^2\sigma^2+4}+n^2\sigma)} < \frac{1}{\sigma}$,
we have $g(x_0) \ge f(x_0)$ that is
$$-(1 - e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}} )x_0^2 - (1 + e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}})\sigma n^2 x_0 + n^2(1 - e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}}) \ge 0$$
which results in
$$x_0 \le -\frac{(1 + e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}})\sigma n^2}{2(1 - e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}})}
+ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(1 + e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}})^2\sigma^2n^4}{(1 - e^{-\frac{4}{\sigma}})^2} + 4n^2}
=: x_u.$$

We have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (x^\ast - x_u) = \frac{2}{(1 + e^{\frac{4}{\sigma}})\sigma}.$$
Thus, $x^\ast - x_0$ does not converge to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer. Just a follow-up question: may we bound from above the term $x^*-x_0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @bgsk You are welcome. I think we can bound it, even $x^\ast - x_0$ converges to some value.